# Parse obj in DRF when use multipart/form-data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   fonts = JSONField() # Postgres
```

I have a nested serializer:

```
PostSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    fonts = FontsSerializer(many=True, required=False)

FontsSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    primary = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    secondary = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
```

Front guys used multipart/form-data to send me data:
[image]

But its not update data on my side. I cant find how to deal with it.
I tried change keys to key.nested:
[image]

And its working.Data is successfully updated.

What way is a correct? 
How can I setup DRF to work with key[nested] template?

P.S: They cant used json, The question about form-data and how to deal with nested inside.

Comment: Can you print out `request.data` in your `post` method from the view?

Comment: I used ModelViewSet and I dont change their method.
But I can print it if you need.

<QueryDict: {'fonts[primary]': ['Ariss'], 'fonts[secondary]': ['Timesdds']}>

Comment: Is this something that they are manually creating?  That doesn't look like any multi-part that I've seen posted before... I only know of `fonts[]` for arrays.  DRF handles this stuff in `utils/html.py@parse_html_dict`.  Was this a PHP app before?

Comment: Nope, they use some JS library for convert to form-data.

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible decision its a create own Parser.

```
class NestedMultipartParser(parsers.MultiPartParser):
"""
Parser for processing nested field values
"""

def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
    result = super().parse(stream=stream, media_type=media_type, parser_context=parser_context)
    data = result.data.copy()
    for key, value in result.data.items():
        if '[' in key and ']' in key:
            del data[key]
            data[key.replace('[', '.').replace(']', '')] = value

    return parsers.DataAndFiles(data, result.files)
```

And then need add in view:

```
parser_classes = (NestedMultipartParser,)
```

But question is still open.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to create your own parser. The problem is on the serializer class. Can you try to use the `source` attribute on `primary = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, source='fonts[primary]')` ?

Comment: Yes, but it will not working with application/json, I wanna have some universal decision.